# Nativescript app performance

Tags: nativescript

I've found {N} app (on Android) to be slow - especially during navigation and noticed that it gets progressively slower as I increase the number of navigations.

I'm thinking it has to do with memory leaks.

I'm developing on Windows and VS Code. Any suggestions on how I can check for memory leaks, performance etc.

Comment: Be sure to run at least 2.4 release. Issues with 2.3 I think with navigation and memory

Comment: You need to specify which version (`tns info`) of both the runtimes and tns-core-modules.

Comment: nativescript 2.4.2; tns-core-modules 2.4.4; tns android 2.4.1

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest version of NativeScript, then my guess would be you are creating new data structures and retaining them during every page navigation.   For example; if you do:

```
var page;
exports.loaded(args) {
    page = args.object;
}
```

And then navigate away, page variable will still be pointing to the entire page element, which will then retain everything relating to the page in memory.  So there are a couple solutions to this.

1. Use WeakRef to maintain references to objects that need to be GC'd.
2. Use the unloaded event to clear all the refs to things that you globalised in your code like our example `page` element above.

One way to determine what is causing the issue is to force a heap dump by putting this code in your android app somewhere:
`__heapSnapshot();`
This will generate a heap snapshot.     Which once you download to your computer you can open in Chrome's developer tools and check out the heap usage.